# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

"SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" This error is not letting me connect to the database instance I created in AWS. I have already changed my database configurations in my .env file at Github repository.

Here is the code:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
 const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE, process.env.DATABASE_USER, 
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD, {
   host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
   dialect: 'mysql',
   // operatorsAliases: false,
   pool: {
   max: 5,
   min: 0,
   acquire: 30000,
   idle: 10000,
  },
});
```